# Make sap.m.CustomTile resizable for resolution e.g. from 500px to 320px

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, sapui5

I customized the sap.m.CustomTile with some sap.m.FormattedText. I need this CustomTile to be resizable according to display resolution e.g. from 500 px to 320 px. I used for this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) { 

    .tileSmall.sapMCustomTile {
        width: 80.9vw !important;
        height: 80.9vw !important;
    }

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) { 

    .tileSmall.sapMCustomTile {
        width: 200px !important;
        height: 200px !important;
    }

}
```

I can not use % because it behaves strange in my app. So I am trying to use vw instead. I did [demo](http://jsbin.com/fepemoqace/1/edit?html,css,output). I would like to keep it all the time as it for resolution 530px in the:

[image]

But when the resolution is change to e.g. 417px I got:

[image]

The resolution  357px I got:

[image]

Is there any way how to anchor footer and subfooter (last two rows)?

Or how to [change](http://jsbin.com/fepemoqace/1/edit?html,css,output) height of the gap (created by br tag) according to tile height?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using VBox inside the custom tile, it is fairly easy to achive what you want. You can check out the [Size Adjustments Explored](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.FlexBox/samples) demo for more examples.

The basic idea is that you can play around with the grow / shrink factors of each item inside the VBox. By default, all the items of a VBox are treated equally and are stretched to fill in the available space. Because you want your header and footer to be fixed, you should set the `shrinkFactor` (default = 1) and `growFactor`(default = 0) to 0 for these items.

The center of the tile should be just "whitespace" to fill in the rest of the available space, so you can give it `growFactor` and `shrinkFactor` equal to 1. You also don't need to put `br`s in there, because the item will grow / shrink dynamically to fill in the remaining space.

You can add these factors for each UI5 Element using the [layoutData](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Element.html#getLayoutData) aggregation and passing a [FlexItemData](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.FlexItemData.html) element.

Another small change is that you should specify `width: "100%"` and `height: "100%` for the VBox to make sure its size adjusts based on the tile's size.

Header / footer

```
   new sap.m.FormattedText({
       htmlText: "whatever you have now",
       layoutData: new sap.m.FlexItemData({
         shrinkFactor: 0
       })
   });
```

Center

```
   new sap.m.FormattedText({
       htmlText: "no need to put anything here",
       layoutData: new sap.m.FlexItemData({
         shrinkFactor: 1,
         growFactor: 1
       })
   });
```

You can find a working version of this solution here: http://jsbin.com/tirizanaje/1/edit?html,css,output